# Is it always OK to not explicitly initialize a value if you would only be setting it to its default value?

Tags: c#

Resharper just prompted me on this line of code:

```
private static bool shouldWriteToDatabase = false;
```

indicating that I should not say " = false" because bools, apparently, [default to false in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx). I've been programming in C# for over a year and a half and never knew that. I guess it just slipped through the cracks, but this leaves me wondering what's good practice.

Do I work on the assumption that default values are understood by all? This would result in cleaner code, but invites ambiguity if another programmer isn't aware of the default value.

Comment: I don't agree with that ReSharper rule and I would disable it immeediately if I had to use ReSharper. Who ever remembers what default values are?

Comment: @DavidePiras While I agree that I disable that rule, I **strongly** disagree with your second statement.  Every C# developer should have a basic understanding of default values - and it's easy in .NET, as the CLI rules for default values are basically "zero" values.  You only have to remember null for reference types, false for bool, and zero for all primitive numeric types.  It only gets odd when you look at types like DateTime, etc - but for those types, the default value is typically never a good initialization value...

Comment: @DavidePiras What default values don't you know?

Comment: @Reed Copsey - You also are unlikely to use types like DateTime without first using DateTime.Now for instance first ( since you know thats required ) new DateTime( ... ) with a specfic value you have in mind.

Comment: I just do not remember, Now thanks to Reed I've learnt something new which make sense, DateTime are nasty and when you enable treat all warnings as errors sometimes you get the error when not assigning a value. I like things to be explicit so if another developer or Me has forgotten these rules can anyway quickly see clearly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I think:

- It's good to be explicit if your code *relies* on the intial value.
- If your code doesn't rely on the initial value, omitting it would make more sense and clutter the code less.

However I don't think Resharper can easily detect the difference between these two situations.

Comment: Okay. I will put resharper in its place, then! :)

Comment: *Why* is it good to be explicit?  Seems like a distraction to me.  I mean, if you don't know that a `bool` defaults to false, then you have other issues...   Seems similar to saying `if (b == true) ...`.  Again, a distraction since it's redundant.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: `bool x = false;` means "I want this member to initially be false." This is very different from `bool x;` which says "Maybe I want this member to initialy be false, or maybe I don't use the initial value, or I may just have forgotten to initialize it. I'll leave you to guess which."

Comment: @Mark, `bool x;` as a *field* declaration simply *always* means (to me) that I mean for it to be false.

Comment: @MarkByers - The default value of a bool is false.   So unless I say otherwise, the value I wanted it to be intialize to, is of course false.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you don't apply the same reasoning to fields that are reference-types, though. ;) However, the same argument could be made: "'I want this member to be null' is very different from 'Maybe I want this member to be initialized but I forgot...'"

Comment: I like being explicit, especially for nullable types `bool? x`;, what the default? :)  Helps other programmers, especially when they may either look for initial values at the definition, in all the constructors, factory methods, or weird initialization methods.

Comment: @MarkByers if you know the language you know that bool defaults to false, there's no guessing in it. Just find in google https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

Comment: Those are facts, not a lottery game to guess anything

Answer (score 4):

Am I the only one who thinks that `= false;` just doesn't clutter the code? As a developer that maintains applications largely written by others, being explicit with what you mean can be very helpful. Yes, bools default to false in C# but when you are looking at someone else's code it can be confusing if this was the intended behavior or if they were just being sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, default values are documented just as well as anything else in a language (C#, or any other language). It's straight forward enough that it should be assumed, i.e. an int starts at 0. A scenario that stands out to me is if you want a huge array of `int`s all holding 0s. Are you going to define that, or just let C# initialize it with 0s?

It seems a little counter-intuitive to assume a large arrays of `int`s to be 0s, but to have to specify that one `bool` is false. Specifying the basic variable but not the more complex structure. So I don't initialize anything to it's default value for the sake of consistency.

Comment: While you make a very good point regarding consistency, you missed out that a) unlike a bool, initializing the contents of an array can't easily be done on one line and b) unlike a bool, there would be a significant extra performance cost in explicitly (re-)initializing the values in an array to their default values. These two points for me mean that it's acceptable to treat the two situations differently. But +1 anyway.